# How to Fix This (.getDownloadUrl()) Not Coming In New Version Of Firebase DataBase

Tags: java

**how to fix .getDownloadUrl() In New Versions Based On My Code**

Am Unable To Find **.getDownloadUrl()** In New Versions Can You Please tell Me The Answer

```
  private void uploadFile() {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, 500);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                            String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Please Sir Fix This Problems

Answer (score 0):

Tl;Dr
Instead of `takeSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()` write, `takeSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl()`

Longer version.

Firebase API has changed a lot, the new `UploadTask.TakeSnapshot` API doesn't have the method `getDownloadUrl()` anymore.

You can use the the method [`getMetaData`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot.html#getMetadata()) which returns a `StorageMetaData` object. The `StorageMetaData` object has a method [`getReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageMetadata.html#getReference()) which returns `StorageReference`, which has the method [`getDownloadUrl`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) which will return you a `Task<uri>` object.

you can also look at [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) piece of code from FireBase docs, where it calls `getDownloadUrl` on `StorageReference` class.

Comment: Thank You Minato Can You Please Write code To Me To Solve This Error Am New To Android Studio Please